# How can I resolve a TypeError where the property of length is undefined, when I have brackets set up to take in a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am building my first react application and following a video from the page JavaScript Mastery (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls). This project teaches me how to build a chart in react using data from an API to display global Covid-19 data. I tried to put the data into an empty array and loop through it using 'dailyData.length' but I keep getting a TypeError with length being undefined.

Here is my Chart.jsx

```
Import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { fetchDailyData } from '../../api';

import { Line,Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

import styles from './Chart.module.css';


const Chart = () => {
   const[dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]); //here is where I set up the empty array.

useEffect(()=> {
   const fetchAPI = async() => {
       setDailyData (await fetchDailyData());

   }
    console.log(dailyData);

   fetchAPI();
});

const lineChart = (
dailyData.length  //this is where I am getting the error
    ? (
    <Line
    data={{

        labels: dailyData.map(({ date }) => date),
        datasets: [{
            data: dailyData.map(({ confirmed }) => confirmed),
            label:'Infected',
            borderColor: '#3333ff',
            fill: true,

        }, {
            data: dailyData.map(({ deaths }) => deaths),
            label:'deaths',
            borderColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', 
            fill: true,

        }],
    }}
/>) : null
```

My Index.js is the following:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api';

export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate} } = await axios.get(url);
    return {confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate};
} catch (error) {
}
}export const fetchDailyData = async()=> {
try{
    const { data } = await axios.get('${url}/daily');
    const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({
        confirmed: dailyData.confirmed.total,
        deaths: dailyData.deaths.total,
        date: dailyData.reportDate,
    }));
    return modifiedData;
} catch(error){
}
}
```

As you can see, I am exporting the data from the API in my Index.js file, and in my Chart.jsx is where I set up the empty array for the data to be looped through. Am I incorrectly setting up my empty array or calling the data incorrectly? Some help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: 
Here is the exact error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Chart
src/components/Chart/Chart.jsx:20
 17 |     fetchAPI();
 18 | });
 19 | 
>20 | const lineChart = ( 
 21 |  ^dailyData.length 
 22 |      ? (
 23 |      <Line
```

Comment: please share the exact error message, and which line (in which file) it refers to

Comment: btw you shouldn't use empty `catch` blocks. Apart from anything else, errors while developing are good because they show you what is wrong. I cannot see anything obviously wrong with your code right now but I am wondering if these empty `catch` blocks are being triggered, which will cause your `fetchXXX` methods to return `undefined` and therefore trigger an error like the one you report.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for the advice! I have updated the post to show the exact error message. I will try manipulating the 'catch' blocks to see if that resolves the error.

Comment: I've figured out where you're going wrong - writing up an answer right now. But note that, had you not put in those `catch` blocks you might have spotted this yourself sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Having inspected the output of the [API](https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily) you are using, I've figured out your mistake.

The output is a JSON array, not an object. So in particular, it has no `data` property.

So when you do `const { data } = await axios.get('${url}/daily')`, `data` will be `undefined`. Therefore you can't `map` over it (`data.map` will be `undefined`, and you will get an "undefined is not a function" error).

The solution is simple: replace the offending line:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('${url}/daily')
```

with

```
const data = await axios.get('${url}/daily')
```

(In case you're unsure, the difference between the two lines is that the second one uses `data` for the entire response - which here is the array you want. The first assumes the response will be an object with a `data` property, and sets the `data` variable to be the corresponding value - which doesn't exist here.)

And finally, as I said in my comment, the reason you didn't spot this was those empty `catch` block in `fetchDailyData`. Empty `catch` blocks are a very bad idea in any circumstance - while you certainly don't want your app to blow up with an error for a real end-user, simply silencing the error as you are here is almost never the right solution, instead you should do something to handle the error and either recover from it or let the user know some problem occurred. But here, as you saw, it doesn't even stop an error, it just leads to another one elsewhere, which is necessarily harder to debug. (The error occurred because, when the error is encountered in `fetchDailyData`, the code inside the `try` stopped and the `catch` was executed instead, which does nothing - with the result that the function returns nothing, ie implicitly returns `undefined`, rather than the array of data you were expecting. And *this* is why the calling component complains about you trying to access a `length` property of `undefined`.)